# Getting a specific value inside dataframe and the position

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a Dataframe similar to the tabel example here, and I want to find a specific value inside this Dataframe, for example the value 2. Herefor i use np.where, in the next step I want to check if there is a next value, and if so is the value smaller/bigger/similar.
My solution would be 'print out the np.where and hardcode the index with [-x] for each value after the 2.' So iam looking for a smarter Solution for cases with for example 100 Values

The output should be: 2 is bigger ,2 is smaller ,2 is the last number.

| Value |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 2 |

Comment: So what should be the output for this specific table?

Comment: On the example table and the condition we are checking out the value 2 the output should be 2 > 1 ,2 <3 and 2 is the last number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you could try this code

```
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2], columns=['num'])

def find_values(df, number):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['num'] == number:
            if len(df) == index+1:
                print(number, 'is the last number')
            else:
                next_num = df.loc[index+1, 'num']
                if next_num > number:
                    print(number, '<', next_num)
                elif next_num < number:
                    print(number, '>', next_num)
                else:
                    print(number, '==', number)

find_values(frame, 2)
```

output:

```
2 > 1
2 < 3
2 is the last number
```

Comment: How can i check the following number after next_num?

Comment: @AchillesDay you can replace the 1 with 2 in the df.loc statement. You have to make sure you're not going over the number of rows in the dataframe though.

Comment: yeah that´s exactly my problem. should i put it inside a try except function? Because i get the data over time.

Comment: if you're going to increase the index + i every time, the easiest way is to try-except it. If you stick to + 1 or +2 you could simply check whether index + i <= len(df)